# Rspec controller test failing with Apostrophe Character?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory, faker

Right now I have unit tests that are failing using the "Faker" Company Name.

it seems like the `expect(response.body).to match(@thing.name)` is whats getting messed up.

When looking at the error, the Faker Company names will sometimes have things like "O'Brian Company" or "O'Hare Company" or similar.

Is faker an encoded string? since I know it's not a good idea to match on encoded strings, and I really don't want to just specify a specific company name in the Factory im using.

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious why you felt like my answer wasn't sufficient. Anything I can clarify?

Comment: The problem with include is that if it "contains" it, I want it to match it completely and not just that the word "exists" within the name. Although I may use it as a fallback, in which ill mark your answer correct :). Im really just trying to look for other possibilities.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Faker won't do any encoding for you. It will just give you a string like `O'Malley`. But the response should have HTML escaping (or some other kind, depending on the format), like `O&#39;Malley`. You could always `puts response.body` to see for sure.

The RSpec `matches` matcher is really designed [for either `expected` or `actual` to be a regular expression](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/match-matcher), but in your case both are strings. Because the code [has an optimization calling `values_match?`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/e6868c3068f2ddb22d639bc338e865a0bbc7a4d2/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/match.rb#L40) which [does a simple comparison](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-support/blob/e96cc73d0a7d46d9b1948d165c52f0aff78e9457/lib/rspec/support/fuzzy_matcher.rb#L15), you are effectively saying `expect(response.body).to eq(@thing.name)`.

If you do want a regular expression, you are right that you should be careful using uncontrolled values to create it. Fortunately Ruby has [`Regexp.escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) for that, so you can say `Regexp.new("foo" + Regexp.escape(@thing.name) + "bar")`. But from your objection to `include`, it sounds like you actually want the response to contain nothing but the name, right? In that case, you don't need a regex at all.

In any case, the problem isn't about what's *around* the name, but how the name is escaped. So before comparing you should either (1) decode the response or (2) encode the faker string. It doesn't really matter which. Both are pretty easy:

```
expect(CGI.unescapeHTML(response.body)).to eq @thing.name
```

or

```
expect(response.body).to eq CGI.escapeHTML(@thing.name)
```

Naturally, if your response is JSON, you should replace all this HTML escaping stuff with JSON, etc.

Comment: Quick question: What is this CGI in your "expect" functions. Is that whats encoding them?

Comment: CGI is part of the Ruby standard library: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are referring to [Faker::Company](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/doc/company.md) of the [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) gem

The correct way to make your example expectation pass would be to use a `Regexp` as in the [@rafael-costa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41943384/260670) example. Doing so escapes things like apostrophes.

The problem with using Faker is that your tests are not deterministic. It is best practice to provide static, known inputs for your test and expect the outputs to pass certain expectations based on those inputs. It is difficult to provide a pertinent example without more information but maybe something like this:

```
company = Company.new(name: 'Acme Anvils')
get :show, params: {id: company.to_param}, session: {}
expect(response.body).to match(Regexp.new('Acme Anvils', Regexp::MULTILINE))
```

Also you typically should not test specific body output within your controller specs. To do so is testing across purposes. You would normally [write a `view` test](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-write-rails-view-test-with-rspec/) for that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try passing a Regexp instead of the string:

```
expect(response.body).to match(Regexp.new(@thing.name))
```

Also, If the problem is only when you get this type of names from faker, then you should take a look at this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34967258/7219974), It gives some good insights.

Comment: I guess the issue in NOT using it, is I would need to define a lot of sample test data. But in a way it's good because it does show issues with odd values for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using #include instead of using #match.

```
expect(response.body).to include(@thing.name)
```

Comment: This does not work